# Limit Table By Latest/Highest Date

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select from a table like this below and limit it by the latest date.

| record_date | Name | Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-05-19 | John | 21 |
| 2021-05-19 | Smith | 25 |
| 2021-05-19 | Mary | 20 |
| 2021-05-20 | Ann | 26 |
| 2021-05-20 | Jane | 23 |

I tried doing

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE(record_date) BETWEEN MAX(DATE(record_date)) AND MAX(DATE(record_date))
```

The above code does not work, but this is what I am trying to acheive below:

| record_date | Name | Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-05-20 | Ann | 26 |
| 2021-05-20 | Jane | 23 |

I don't want to hard-code the date into the statement, because records come in everyday, so it has to be able to select the latest date and limit only that. Thanks!

Comment: Well it would make more sense to make that an `where record_date = (SELECT MAX(record_date) from table)`

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
select * from table where record_date = (select max(record_date) from table)
```

Answer (score 0):

One more query using `JOIN`

```
select t.* 
from t
join (select max(record_date) max_date from t) max_date_t on record_date = max_date;
```

[MySQL fiddle](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=748ee99956b74847f19c9d754c1ccc3f&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)